Spring Boot 3: Exclude REST Endpoints from Authorization
I am using Spring Boot 3 for my REST application and want to exclude some REST Endpoints from Authorization.
Take this REST Controller as an example:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/rest/products")
class ProductController { ... }

My Security config looks like this:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.
                    requestMatchers("/api/rest/products").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );
    ...
}

But this doesn't work. The /products endpoint still demands an Authorization Header. It only works when I provide a regex like this:
requestMatchers("**").permitAll()

Now all endpoints won't require the Auth header. What am I doing wrong? I haven't yet found a proper string to only exclude the /products endpoint.

Add anonymous authentication that way there will be an anonymous authorization token and you can access the endpoint.

If you want to exclude some of the REST endpoints from authorization, I would suggest using the WebSecurityCustomizer in your configuration file. Once you manually add the WebSecurityCustomizer, the bean will be automatically used by the WebSecurityConfiguration. I have added a sample code example below.
 @Bean
 public WebSecurityCustomizer ignoringCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/ignore1", "*/ignoreRequest");
 }


I have the same issue here: Only the string "**" works, but then it works for all endpoints. If I provide a specific one, then it doesn't work (like "/api/rest/products"). Maybe its a regex issue?

You must provide the endpoints, such as '/api/rest/products/**'. I think it will work for you.
